# Printing values separated by space

Tags: php

I have a `foreach` loop which prints values of two variables:

```
$Var1 = '';
$Var2 = '';
foreach($variable as $key => $value)
{
   $Var1 .= $value->Id;
   $Var2 .= $value->Name;
}
echo $Var1;
echo $Var2;
```

If the loop runs 3 times, the result is:

```
Var1_value_1 Var1_value_2 Var1_value_3

Var2_value_1 Var2_value_2 Var2_value_3
```

But I want the following:

```
Var1_value_1 Var2_value_1 Var1_value_2 Var2_value_2 Var1_value_3 Var2_value_3
```

Comment: So messy question :(

Comment: Please Read the question. just want to print value of 1st variable the other, again print 1st variable the second one..

Comment: What does `$variable` contain? You need to be specific and provide adequate details before you expect someone to solve it for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$variable` is an array of objects with properties `Id` and `Name`, then you can print it this way:

```
$a = [];
foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
   $a [] = $value->Id . ' ' . $value->Name;
}
echo implode(' ', $a);
```

where we simply concatenate the strings, [push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) them into the `$a` array, then build the final string with [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Or even this way:

```
echo implode(' ', array_map(function ($v) {
  return $v->Id . ' ' . $v->Name;
}, $variable));
```

[`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) applies the callback for each array item (`$v`). The callback returns modified item, the result of concatenation. Finally, the items of the new array are joined by [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).